# SAML SSO - received urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:AuthnFailed error status on saml response from IdP

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, pingfederate

Our app lies on SAML SSO 2.0 for login. We just got this error in the saml response status from the IdP and I'm not sure what this actually means and what needs to be done in order to get it fixed.

The Identity Provider our clients are using is Ping Federate and we have already configured SSO settings successfully between their IdP and our app long before. 
No issue so far and now suddenly we're getting this Authentication Failed error out of nowhere while the user tries to login.

**Can some one clarify what this actually means?**

**There hasn't been any change on the app (Service Provider) side on the SSO recently so does this mean the issue is on the IdP end?**

Let me know. Thanks.

Here's the saml response (signature & client identifers changed)

```
<samlp:Response Version="2.0" ID="hbj8oC64PBip6qPoM9jrpS1OCfI" IssueInstant="2018-08-28T15:16:43.824Z" InResponseTo="_9a55c2b67dcd76cee19828ff496206a61b4c51237c" Destination="https://exampleapp.com/saml/login/callback" 
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">foobar</saml:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="#hbj8oC64PBip6qPoM9jrpS1OCfI">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>rVffko3J5H6izfHOi4m0r4vtLHVLKbZqX6VmhYW7wIw=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
CuLJsdfsdfxc9C81bcFYtahXu98eS2izTwXUp7Hi592Qh5/b/bNgyaDjV1l3r0R4dcx+wP6IDPnqIxpk7h BezfbD8bqm1cBC3AFgLh0b9RByGto2qpxJv1HP1sMkAk03x6JPq7ec6fAFJdrkeKMq5dyl8eodjy lNu0Ql3qY3k1gIerTToQZULkAZp8WLIekPpaOKzvXotzZx3dLoprn/XA+BKZZgR8WP7jZ4t/3jJF YF1l2WjaSWOJgoz8PIjwPJZ7mvqjvYbY3u726vra3x+c0wzp+qlNZNbUzqg2CQ07RICMgHbnLKMA /PiF81helnjOCOdOTIrFmkxoiwvYz3Th6/1sLA==
        </ds:SignatureValue>
    </ds:Signature>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder">
            <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:AuthnFailed"/>
        </samlp:StatusCode>
        <samlp:StatusMessage>Authentication Failed</samlp:StatusMessage>
        <samlp:StatusDetail>
            <Cause>org.sourceid.websso.profiles.idp.FailedAuthnSsoException</Cause>
        </samlp:StatusDetail>
    </samlp:Status>
</samlp:Response>
```

Comment: `status:Responder` suggests an issue at the IdP side. Check logs and perform common maintenance, it could be something as trivial as the database went offline etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the issue is on the IDP end: it was not able to authenticate the user for some reason. The logs at the IDP side should tell you (or: them) more.